# Not able to call AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working to create some HTML table by JSON data. I have a servlet from where I am returning some data into JSON format and manipulating this JSON data with javascript. Where I am stuck is my AJAX is not calling.

I have a form where 3 inputs are there **FROMDATE, TO DATE and OUTLET** outlet is in select option having options 1 as "ALL" and 3 more are there

Here is my HTML form:

```
      <form id="formId" method="get">
            <div class="container">
                <h4>Start Date:</h4>
                <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />

                <h4>End Date:</h4>
                <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
                    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />


                <h4>Outlets:</h4>
                <select name="outlet" id="all">
                    <option>ALL</option>
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.outlet}">
                        <option>${item}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>

                <br>

                <br>
                <div>

                    <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    <div id="tbl"></div>     //after calling AJAX successfully  here i would populate my table

<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/DateWiseOlWiseCounterWisejs.js"></script>
```

Now in my JavaScript, I am writing some logic to populate table as I want and calling ajax but that's not successful

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formId").submit(function(event) {




        $.ajax({
            url : "DateWiseOlwiseCounterWiseServlet",
            method : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : {
                   fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
                   todate : $("#enddate").val(),
                   outlet : $("#all").val()

                 },

            success : function(data) {

//          console.log("test",tableValue);
            $("#formId").hide();
            var dataObj = formatData(data);
            addTable(dataObj);



            }

        });






function formatData(data) {
          let toReturn = [];
          let dateWiseObj = {};
          let maxUniqueForOutlets = {};
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            if (!maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]]) {
              maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]] = [];
            }
            if (maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].indexOf(d["counter"]) == -1) {
              maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].push(d["counter"]);
            }

            if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]]) {
              dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]] = {};
              dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
              dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
            } else {
              if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]]) {
                dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
                dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
              } else {
                if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]]) {
                  dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
                }
              }
            }

          });

          return {
            dateWiseObj: dateWiseObj,
            maxUniqueForOutlets: maxUniqueForOutlets
          };
        };


        function addTable(dataObj) {
          let dateWiseObj = dataObj.dateWiseObj;
          let maxUniqueForOutlets = dataObj.maxUniqueForOutlets;
          let table = document.createElement("table");
          let thead = document.createElement("thead");
          let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
          let th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerHTML = "Outlet";
          headerRow.appendChild(th);
          th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerHTML = "Total";
          headerRow.appendChild(th);
          Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(d) {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = d;
            th.colSpan = maxUniqueForOutlets[d].length + 1;
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
          });
          table.appendChild(thead);
          thead.appendChild(headerRow);

          headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
          th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerHTML = "Date";
          headerRow.appendChild(th);
          th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerHTML = "Counter";
          headerRow.appendChild(th);
          Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(k) {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = "Total";
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
            maxUniqueForOutlets[k].forEach(function(d) {
              th = document.createElement("th");
              th.innerHTML = d;
              headerRow.appendChild(th);
            });
          });
          table.appendChild(thead);
          thead.appendChild(headerRow);

          let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
          Object.keys(dateWiseObj).forEach(function(k) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");

            let td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = k;
            row.appendChild(td);

            grandTotal = 0;
            outletWiseTotal = {};
            Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
              outletWiseTotal[d] = 0;
              if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
                Object.keys(dateWiseObj[k][d]).forEach(function(i) {
                  outletWiseTotal[d] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
                });
              }
              grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[d];
            });
            td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = grandTotal;
            row.appendChild(td);

            Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
              td = document.createElement("td");
              td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[d];

              row.appendChild(td);
             maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
                td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = dateWiseObj[k][d][i] ? dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] : "0";
                row.appendChild(td);
              });
            });
            tbody.appendChild(row);
            //console.log(outletWiseTotal);
          });
          table.appendChild(tbody);
          let divContainer = document.getElementById("tbl");
          divContainer.innerHTML = "";
          divContainer.appendChild(table);
          table.classList.add("table");
          table.classList.add("table-striped");
          table.classList.add("table-bordered");
        }
    });
});
```

I am calling the function call inside the success function but nothing is happening. as on clicking on submit button it just reloads the page not even calling the JavaScript file. I am calling my JS file externally or internally nothing is happening.

Comment: You need `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your submit handler, or the form submission will reload the page before your script can get and process the data - exactly as you're seeing.

Comment: @RobinZigmond yupp you are right i was making that silly mistake..thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the default behavior with `event.preventDefault()`:

```
 $("#formId").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Because you bound a submit event on the form and in turn you are calling one ajax request. Thus you need to stop the default behavior of the form via as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

`<button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>`

to

`<button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>`

and Use click event instead of `form.submit`

`$("#button").click(function(event) {`

Or you can use `event.preventDefault();`